# Increase yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb value in yarn-site.xml

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb value is set as 143360 MB in yarn-site.xml . I got below error while running pyspark job in oozie.I want to increase its value in yarn-site.xml but i don't have permissions to increase it's value.

I there a way i can set yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb value in oozie ?
or copy yarn-site.xml(from server) to my local/hdfs directory , increase its value and then call it in Oozie workflow ?

Error:

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, Required executor memory (133120+22000 MB) is above the max threshold (143360 MB) of this cluster! Please check the values of 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required executor memory (133120+22000 MB) is above the max threshold (143360 MB) of this cluster! Please check the values of 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.

```
Oozie workflow :

 <action name="spark-node" cred="hcred">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${value}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${value}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${value}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <master>yarn</master>
             <mode>cluster</mode>
             <jar>xyz.py</jar>
            <spark-opts>${sparkopts}</spark-opts>
           </spark>
```

Comment: No you can't. It's a ResourceManager setting, you must change its conf then restart the service to reset the value.